# wait for the UI thread to complete or cancel the wait

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, console

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        PressAnyKey.Cancel();
     });
     Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key or don't...");
     PressAnyKey.WaitOne();
  }
}

internal class PressAnyKey
{
  private static Thread inputThread;
  private static AutoResetEvent getInput;
  private static AutoResetEvent gotInput;
  private static CancellationTokenSource cancellationtoken;

  static PressAnyKey()
  {
    // Static Constructor called when WaitOne is called (technically Cancel too, but who cares)
    getInput = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    gotInput = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    inputThread = new Thread(ReaderThread);
    inputThread.IsBackground = true;
    inputThread.Name = "PressAnyKey";
    inputThread.Start();
  }

  private static void ReaderThread()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      // ReaderThread waits until PressAnyKey is called
      getInput.WaitOne();
      // Get here 
      // Inner loop used when a caller uses PressAnyKey
      while (!Console.KeyAvailable && !cancellationtoken.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
      }
      // Release the thread that called PressAnyKey
      gotInput.Set();
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Signals the thread that called WaitOne should be allowed to continue
  /// </summary>
  public static void Cancel()
  {
    // Trigger the alternate ending condition to the inner loop in ReaderThread
    if(cancellationtoken== null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Must call WaitOne before Cancelling");
    cancellationtoken.Cancel();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Wait until a key is pressed or <see cref="Cancel"/> is called by another thread
  /// </summary>
  public static void WaitOne()
  {
    if(cancellationtoken==null || cancellationtoken.IsCancellationRequested) throw new InvalidOperationException("Must cancel a pending wait");
    cancellationtoken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    // Release the reader thread
    getInput.Set();
    // Calling thread will wait here indefiniately 
    // until a key is pressed, or Cancel is called
    gotInput.WaitOne();
  }    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We could *assume* you're looking for feedback on any/all aspects of the code, but it would be better if you could [edit] your question to describe what the code is doing / what problem it's solving, what concerns you might have, etc. - take a look at [Simon's guide for posting a good question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/23788) for a few helpful tips.

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks for pointing me towards the etiquette. I'll revise the question.

Comment: @Mat'sMug can you point me towards the meta question for proper etiquette on what's considered the correct answer?

Comment: I rolled back the last edit; modifying/updating the OP in response to answers makes it hard to relate answers to the code - see [help/someone-answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more details. As for "the correct answer", [which answer to accept?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/73/23788) seems relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you don't just use the cancellation token to stop the thread? I'm also wondering why you're using an explicit thread at all. This is asynchronous programming the ***hard*** way. [async-await](/questions/tagged/async-await) and `Task`s are the idiomatic way to do this for the last several versions of the language & framework.

I'm imagining your code looking something like this. (Totally untested. Might not compile.)

```
public static void Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cts.Token;

    Task.Run(()=>
    {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            await Task.Delay(50);
        }

        token.Cancel();
     }, token);

     Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key or don't...");

     await Task.Delay(50000, token);
     token.Cancel(); //task is still running, best to shut it down too
 }
```

Comment: <pedantic> it's a compiler error to use await from an entry point - CS4009: 'Program.Main()': an entry point cannot be marked with the 'async' modifier

Comment: <pedantic> you can't call Cancel on a CancellationToken, just the CancellationTokenSource

Comment: any reason = because I've been stuck writing async code in the old methodology. It doesn't occur to me to use the newer idioms because I'm locked into older versions of the framework and compiler. You'll laugh, because I had to remember that Task.Run is a shortcut for Task.Factory.StartNew... thanks for the feedback, and suggestion for an alternative.

Comment: Like I said, the code was untested because I was typing directly into the browser. It was only intended to illustrate the concept.

Comment: @JJS if you're locked into an old version of a compiler, it's usually best to mention it in your question so that people don't make suggestions you can't use. I'm sorry about that. Truly. I'll try to take a second look later. What version are you using?

Comment: apologies, I missed the parenthetical note that your code was untested. This was my first post on codereview, I'm not familiar with all the protocols of posting restrictions and good question format. Sorry to frustrate you.

Comment: Don't be sorry @JJS. I just want you to have a good experience on CR.